# Novel about Soviets winning the Cold War

Tags: story-identification, novel, alternate-history

I don’t remember the plot beyond a few salient points:

1. It was an alternate history in which the Soviets won the Cold War.
2. There was a description towards the beginning of new apartment buildings where all the walls were made of glass. The idea was that a true Soviet citizen would have nothing to hide from the People or the State and so should embrace being completely visible at all hours of the day by everybody.
3. I think it took place in London. That may be my memory filling in though because of the cover.
4. The cover showed Big Ben with the Red Army marching underneath.

It was a paperback, and I think I read it around 1999.

Comment: There are [a few books](https://www.alternatehistory.com/forum/threads/books-where-soviets-win-the-cold-war.392220/) with this theme.

Comment: @Randal'Thor did a google image search of all the books mentioned and none of them had a similar cover. One or two of them I’ve read and know are not the one I’m talking about. Thanks for the link tho.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be "We," by Yevgeny Zamyatin? There was a 1993 edition by Penguin.

It is out of copyright and available on the web.
From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_(novel):

"Like all other citizens of One State, D-503 lives in a glass apartment building and is carefully watched by the secret police, or Bureau of Guardians. D-503's lover, O-90, has been assigned by One State to visit him on certain nights. She is considered too short to bear children and is deeply grieved by her state in life."

Full text:
https://biblio.wiki/wiki/We

Comment: Nice catch! And welcome to the site.

Comment: Wow, no that’s not it but well done. This book was definitely not that old- 60’s-90’s.